# Виртуальные диски как в Денвере

Tags: windows

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать папку на компе как виртуальный диск. По аналогии, как сделано в Денвере. Решение интересует под XP и семерку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUBST](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst)

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что надо. А можно как-то задать метку такого диска? Команда label в данном случае работать не будет.

Comment: Смысл? Ты планируешь что с этим диском делать? 
Он автоматом присваивает метку того диска с которого взята папка на виртуальный диск.


ps "палец вверх" за ответ и принять нужно.

Comment: Вообщем метку задать похоже нельзя :(

Comment: Ну, это как бы бессмысленно. 

Диски обычно создают для проверки чего либо, либо чтобы в данный момент быстро добираться до нужной папки или работать с чем-то конкретно в данный момент.

Задумываться о том какая метка будет у только что созданного диска? зачем, ты знаешь уже его букву, тем более в cmd к диску ты явно обращаешься не через Label его а через букву, так что это все лишние телодвижения.